Run an async function from a sync function within an already-running event loop
In my Python application, I have a sync function boo() that is called inside a running event loop. boo() has to get some data from foo(arg1, arg2), which is an async function.
Unfortunately, I can't turn boo() into an async function. It must stay synchronized. (This constraint is out of my hands).
How can I call foo(arg1, arg2) from within boo(), wait until it completes, and continue the execution?
Minimal Reproducible Example
I tried to create a minimal reproducible example. This is the closest I could get. The real application is big and complex, and may behave differently.
import time
import asyncio

async def work_for_data():
    time.sleep(3)
    return 42

# sync function, calling async function
def get_number():
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(work_for_data())

async def get_data():
    return get_number()

async def run():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = asyncio.create_task(get_data())
    loop.run_until_complete(task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run())

This code raises:
  File "./minimal_example.py", line 9, in get_number
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(work_for_data())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 629, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 588, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Attempts To Solve The Problem
I made a lot of attempts to solve it, all of them didn't work.
Attempt 1
data = asyncio.run(foo(arg1, arg2))

Raised the following exception:
    data = asyncio.run(foo(arg1, arg2))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydevd_asyncio/pydevd_nest_asyncio.py", line 143, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1511, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1504, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1377, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_forever
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 518, in uvloop.loop.Loop._run
RuntimeError: this event loop is already running.

Attempt 2
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
data = loop.run_until_complete(foo(arg1, arg2))

Raised the following exception:
    data = loop.run_until_complete(foo(arg1, arg2))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1511, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1504, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1377, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_forever
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 518, in uvloop.loop.Loop._run
RuntimeError: this event loop is already running.

Attempt 3
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future = executor.submit(lambda: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(foo(arg1, arg2), loop).result())
        data = future.result()

The interpreter got stuck when executing future.result()
Attempt 4
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.Future()

    def callback(task):
        if task.exception():
            future.set_exception(task.exception())
        else:
            future.set_result(task.result())

    task = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(foo(arg1, arg2), loop)
    task.add_done_callback(callback)

    result = task.result()  ## Stuck here
    return result

The interpreter got stuck when executing task.result()

What does "None of this worked." mean? Just asyncio.run() ought to work, anyway.

I tried asyncio.run() too, but it raised a runtime error (edited the question and included the details)

OK, so a loop is already running, then the other ways you've tried should work. If they don't, then you'll again need to provide a [mre] and clarify what exactly "doesn't work" means.

Yes, I mentioned in the beginning that a loop is already running. All the methods I described in the question did not work. I updated the question with the errors I get

https://pypi.org/project/nest-asyncio/ -- it's abandonware, but it works. At least, it works for me; I don't use uvloop.

You probably have to call boo while the event loop is running, but do you have to have the event loop run it? Calling boo itself in an executor and having boo use run_coroutine_threadsafe to run async calls should work.

btw, good question -- thank you for doing the work of showing your attempts and the associated errors.

@user2357112, ...does your proposal differ from "Attempt 3"?

I tried to install nest-asyncio, import it, and call nest_asyncio.apply() in the application entry point. Unfortunately I still see this error

@CharlesDuffy: Yes. Attempt 3 is still running inside the event loop. boo itself needs to run in an executor. It can't just delegate to the executor to call run_coroutine_threadsafe.

There is no straightforward way to do that - usually, async functions can only be called from async functions: that´s just the way it is meant to work.
The reason is that any intermediate synchronous function in a call of chains is not expected to be "paused" when an inner function makes an await statement and expecting the loop to run other concurrent tasks: there are no mechanisms for the synchronous function in the way to be paused and resumed - that is what the async def does.
So, the obvious and correct approach is just to make all your calling chaing to a function that will need to await an I/O operation (or equivalent), has to be composed of async calls.
Sometimes this can lead to duplicated code - with very similar functions existing, meant to be called one from sync and one from async code, and even large code bases and advanced frameworks struggle to overcome that.
HOWEVER if your inner function won´t need the result of calling an async function itself, - i.e., it can just create a task with the async function, and return  that task - the async function calling the synchronous function should then keep the returned task and await for it:
Keep in mind that callback loaded code can be confusing to follow along, and that is actually one of the main motivations for the incorporation of all the async-enabling syntax and mechanisms in the language in the first place.
So, for code that simply does´t need the return value:
import asyncio

async def work_for_data():
    time.sleep(3)
    return 42

# sync function, calling async function
def get_number():
    task = asyncio.create_task(work_for_data())
    return task

async def get_data():
    # trigger sync function that will start the tasks for producing async data
    number_task = get_number()
    # do more concurrent stuff
    
    ...
    # await for the data produced by `get_number()`:
    number = await number_task

async def run()
    global queue

    task = asyncio.create_task(get_data())
    await task


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run())

Other approaches are to to have the synchronous code to create a task for  an intermediate function that will await the target async function, and put its return value in a queue, which then could be consumed elsewhere - whenever the result is ready. Or if the snchronous function will have code itself which needs to deal with the values produced in the async code, then, the way to do it is through setting a callback, by calling the .add_done_callback method on the created task . The result of the processing of this callback won't be returned to the async function calling the sync (get_number) function though. If that is needed, than the plain approach of just making all your call chain async is preferrable.

I have a similar issue, but instead of just any ordinary synchronous function that calls the asynchronous one, it is a property accessor, which cannot be rewritten to be async. My guess is that if I posted it as a question, it would get closed as a duplicate for being too similar to this one. I found that the nest-asyncio package works around this limitation, but it results in ResourceWarnings.

A property which needs to behave as if it were asynchronous can simply createa new task, wrapping the async work it should perform and return that task. Whoever is using the property then just have to await for the property - it will behave transparently as if it were async:
class A:\n    @property\n    def b(self): return asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(1))  ```  And the user code: `x = await A().b` will just work.

that could work, though it would make the use pattern somewhat obnoxious, e.g. something = (await model.related).column_name. I experimented with this briefly, but the amount of refactoring would be insane since I have a hundred unit tests and 2 integration tests.

I see you created another question.
There are ways to further wrap the returned task so that could work without the parenthesis. But without the await keyword, that will require some more hacks - not sure if it is possible!

There is no problem with scheduling an async function from within a sync function, but in asyncio (and with a single thread) it is not possible that a sync function waits for a result. If the control is not returned to the scheduler, no other function could be run and no result will be computed. Every function (sync or async) executed within an asyncio event loop belongs to a task and there can be only one running task at a time.
You must use multiple threads and one of them will run the event loop. The other thread(s) can submit work and wait for the result. Here is how: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading

It's not recommended to call async function from sync function, since it involves communication between threads, and makes the whole program blocked. A good way to solve this is to make your sync functions adapted to async parts, and make the whole program async.
However, there's some workaround that could "solve" your issue.

Wrap the async part into asyncio.loop
Handle data communication between sync and async part.

import asyncio

async def calc_async():
    # Use asyncio.sleep to non-blockingly wait for 2 seconds
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return 10

def sync_function():
    # Set up a new event loop for running async code
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        # Run the async function until complete and get the result
        result = loop.run_until_complete(calc_async())
        return result
    finally:
        # Close the loop to clean up resources
        loop.close()

# Example usage
result = sync_function()
print("Result from async function:", result)

